# Can't change selected option

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a dropdownlist with data-bind;

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbType" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" data-bind="value: moveType">
  <asp:ListItem Value="">-- Please Select --</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Car</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Air</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

When page is loaded, by default (as I understand, are selected first option).
The issue is that I can't change this selection at all.

I tried second things:

```
$('#cmbType option[value=' + d.Type + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

or

```
$("#cmbType").val(d.Type);
```

or

```
var viewModel = {
  this.moveType = ko.observable(d.Type);

};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());​
```

d.Type = 0 or 1.

Actually, all variants seems to be working. They change visible value to chosen one (Car or Air) BUT when I'm trying to get selected value, I am getting value="" (-- Please Select--).

What can it be when dropdown show that one of options was selected (Car or Air) but the real selected option are still (-- Please Select --)?

Comment: because there are server side controls in asp.net so set clientid mode as static.

Comment: Try with this $("[id$='cmbType']").val(d.Type);. Because server will change its id before rendering.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Inside a datagrid or user control it may be an issue.

Comment: @Dalorzo how? always the rendered id ends with the client id. I'm not 100% sure. Please excuse me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I am referring to something called `ClientIDRowSuffix` that is added at the end of the controls in some circumstances and in case of UserControls if you add 2 in the same page 2 controls will meet the criteria for the same querySelector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#<%=cmbType.ClientID %> option[value=' + d.Type + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

> **ClientID**: Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

You may also change the `ClientIDMode` of the control to `Static` which will preserve the value you set in your `Id` property.